# Have you used Perf4J to collect and analyze performance metrics in Java app?

Tags: java, performance, aop, jmx, perf4j

Did you use [Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/index.html) in your Java application to collect and analyze performance stats?

What was the typical pattern (using log files, utilities, UI, JMX, etc.)?

Did you use annotations and AOP-based features?

Did you use any JMX integration?

How did you handle production configuration?

Did you include performance stats views/reports as a feature in your application?

Please tell if and why you decided on alternative library/approach.

Comment: Have came across Perf4J but never tried it so would be interested too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using Per4j to monitor webservice endpoint performance and also internal service and dao class performance.

I mainly just log the raw performance statistics to a daily rolling file. Then i use the jar on the command line to analyse the data with different timeslices as i please. I often use the `-g` commandline option to output a html file which i can then open up and view the data visually which is really useful.

I enjoy using Spring AOP with the `@Profiled` annotation. It makes timing very clean. I had a few doubters regarding perf4j degrading performance, and i could easily offer that i could turn the logging off by removing the `TimingAspect` from my Spring applicationContext.xml file.

```
<!-- just remove and all uses of @Profiled do nothing -->
<bean id="timingAspect" class="org.perf4j.log4j.aop.TimingAspect"/>
```

Becareful about the mean value and note the max value. While doing performance tuning, we had a method call having wild values with a large standard deviation. Most of the values were around the median, however there were a sprinkling of calls which were 100x more than the average. More of user error than anything, but watch out.

I use the`AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender` with a timeslice of 15000, but hardly read the log. Because i have the raw performance logs, I can chop and change that by running perf4j on the command line.

I tried out the JMX integration and it works as promised from the documentation. But I have no real use at the moment for it.

I have plans to expose the data using SNMP and if it's useful i'll contribute.

In all, i recommend Perf4j.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Perf4J in a client-server application for timing RPC calls. It was quite simple to implement: I only needed to include a few lines of code around the RPC dispatcher servlet to measure each RPC method call. Time measurements are written to a separate log file, aggregated data is kept in memory for usage with the graphing servlet. Configuration was a matter of minutes.

This is an excerpt from the preHandle() method:

```
request.setAttribute("stopWatch", new CommonsLogStopWatch());
```

This code from the postHandle() method:

```
LoggingStopWatch stopWatch = (LoggingStopWatch)request.getAttribute("stopWatch");
stopWatch.stop(methodName);
```

Here are the relevant sections of my log4j.cfg:

```
<logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CoalescingStatistics"/>
    <appender-ref ref="statsAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="CoalescingStatistics"
          class="org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
    <param name="TimeSlice" value="60000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="graphPatientChart"/>
</appender>

<appender name="graphPatientChart"
          class="org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
    <param name="GraphType" value="Mean"/>
    <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="getPatientChart,idleNotification"/>
</appender>

<appender name="statsAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="file" value="WEB-INF/log/meona-performance.log"/>
    <param name="append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I'd like the graphing servlet to be more interactive: It would be nice if I could choose the tags to be included in the graph. Have you come across an UI application that can be used to analyze the time measurement logs?

Comment: Matthias, thank you. No, I didn't have a chance to continue using perf4j yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Perf4J, and eventually ditched it because I was already using Spring AOP. I would love to simply integrate the two , but was having trouble with it (because of the Perf4J appenders).

I tried to use Perf4j through annotations and AOP without JMX.
You can handle production cfg through configuration files.

Overall, I liked the Perf4j approach but since I was already using Spring for performance monitoring I didn't need perf4j. One thing that Perf4j gives for free is the min/max/standard dev; with other libs you would have to do the math yourself.

I thing perf4j is nice if you don't have any other lib that can provides interception (aspectJ or AOP), but since I already had spring it was easier to implement performance measurement. You can easily expose bean properties through JMX with Spring.